# How can I get media keys working on my keyboard?

Tags: 11.10, microsoft-keyboard

Just got a new keyboard, the Microsoft comfort curve 2000, and everything seems to work fine except for the 'back' and 'forward' multimedia keys.

I am running Ubuntu 11.10 and have tried going into system settings -> keyboard -> shortcuts, then I try and hold down the keys to set the action I want them to perform, but nothing changes.

Any thoughts on where else to look?

-- UPDATE --

I rebooted and the options to change the keyboard shortcuts seem to be working now. Now I can tweak the whole thing and I managed to assign the media keys correctly.

Thanks to everybody for the suggetions

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MultimediaKeys

Comment: File a bug report on Launchpad. Include output from `sudo lsusb --verbose`.

Comment: Ubuntu 11.10 is definitely too damn old.  Please upgrade.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following; consider them as different tests.

1. Run `showkey` (will perhaps require root privileges). This application will tell you if your key is being read or ignored by the system.
2. Install and run `dconf-editor`. Go to `org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys` and set `next` to `XF86AudioNext` and `prev` to `XF86AudioPrev`.

Comment: According to showkey the keys are being read 'keycode 158' for back and 'keycode 159' for forward. Should I input those to dconf-editor or the codes you suggested? The media keys are currently set to your suggestions

Comment: I was thinking about that. I don't think so, I just suggested the application so you could see if your key presses were being read. I think that the solution might be to assign the the XF86 fake keys to your keycodes. I have no idea how to do that, but I think it has to do with `xmodmap`

Comment: Check either the manual or this website: http://www.xfree86.org/4.2.0/xmodmap.1.html
You can set fake keys (keysyms) to keycodes, but perhaps it is a better idea to find out how to get your system to match the correct keyboard.

Comment: So what do you do if they are ignored in 1?

Comment: It works fine using Vortex Keyboards like Poker 3

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the 11.10 upgrade resets the keyboard layout setting in System Settings. The Single Quote (') and Double Quote (") buttons besides a few others was not working for me subsequent to the upgrade.

I had to go to System Settings > Keyboard > Layout Settings and add English (US) from the list and remove the English (International with dead keys) choice.

Is this a bug in the upgrade?

Answer (score -1):

Check you have the right keyboard model selected.
System Settings->Keyboard->Layouts->Keyboard Model->Microsoft Curve 2000

(I'm on 11.04 and this keyboard is listed so it should be on 11.10)

Comment: They do not list the keyboard makes in 11.10 from what I can see, just the language and then the list of variations, nothing to set the specific keyboard make/model. Like I said above, you can go into the keyboard settings and should be able to assign the keys but when I assign them for the keyboard nothing changes