# Some keys are not detected in my keyboard (multimedia keys?) by either xev or xbindkeys or keytouch: how to detect them?

Tags: lubuntu, openbox, dconf, xev, xbindkeys

It is one more attempt to get `Fn` keys to volume up/down, brightness, etc. working. Those controls are simply not working in my non-branded ultrabook.

I want to detect them to modify `/home/username/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml`, as the following doesn't seem working:

```
<keybind key="XF86AudioRaiseVolume">
    <action name="Execute">
        <command>amixer -q sset Master 3%+ unmute</command>
```

Neither `xev` nor `xbindkeys` nor `keytouch` are detecting when I press volumen up or brightness down, for example. The start/stop touchpad button is working, but is not detected by those applications either.

I also tried with `dconf-editor` as it is suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72562/how-can-i-get-media-keys-working-on-my-keyboard). `next` was already set to `XF86AudioNext` (and it is `active`)

[Here](https://askubuntu.com/a/5235/279148), I read the following explanation:

> Some laptop <kbd>Fn</kbd> key combinations are multimedia keys
>   (appearing to the OS as ordinary keys with nonstandard codes), while
>   others trigger ACPI events that eventually reach the OS, and some are
>   just handled by the BIOS and never seen by the OS. The information
>   paths are explained on the
>   [Hotkeys/Architecture](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Hotkeys/Architecture)
>   page on the Ubuntu wiki, complete with diagrams.
>
> If the OS can't see anything when you press the brightness keys, it
>   could be because they're handled directly by the BIOS. The battle is
>   not completely lost — it is in principle possible to hack the BIOS —
>   but the difficulty level is considerably raised.

Any idea?

Comment: What kind of keyboard is it? It is possible that your keyboard has some keys that use keycodes > 255, in which case they are not supported by Xorg, see [freedesktop bug #11227](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=11227). It is a long standing problem that won't be fixed until the world leaves Xorg behind.

Comment: `xev` doesn't report the *keycodes* for your keypresses, but does the kernel see the *scancodes*? You should be able to check `dmesg` output and see messages like `Unknown key pressed (translated set 2, code 0xa0 on isa0060/serio0` - alternately you might try `sudo showkey --scancodes`

Comment: @bain, the keyboard is a US Keyboard. I have set it to Spanish though. Lubuntu has set the keyboard model to pc105 by default. On the oher hand, I don't understand the topic of that link well: isn't it possible to use XI2 instead Xorg? But firstly, how could we know if the keyboard uses keycodes > 255?

Comment: @JamesS., `showkey` has the same result than `xev`, `xbindkeys` or `keytouch`. I typed `dmesg | grep -i 'key'`, `dmesg | grep -i 'translated'`, etc: the result is empty.

Comment: Switch to the console with ctrl-alt-f1 and hit the key. See the instructions at [Ubuntu wiki MultimediaKeys](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MultimediaKeys).

Comment: @bain, I push `ctrl-alt-f1` and the multimedia keys in the console. Then, I type`dmesg | grep 'key'`. The result is empty. Is it what you are asking me to do?

Comment: Check your BIOS' settings.

Comment: @FuzzyToothpaste, unfortunately, no options related to the keyboard in the BIOS

Comment: So, it sounds very much as though your keyboard and BIOS do not in fact float keypress events for those keys to the OS layer. It makes me curious how those keys would work at all even in Windows if they are not working now, but I have no further speculation.

Answer (score 1):

You may need acpi support

```
sudo apt-get install acpi acpi-support acpica-tools acpid acpidump acpitail acpitool libacpi0 laptop-detect pommed
```

Beyond installing the above packages, I finally fixed this issue on my laptop by **uninstalling** the `toshet` package after discovering my specific model was not compatible or supported by the toshet application. I doubt you have `toshet` installed but you can check to see by typing the following command:

```
dpkg -l | grep toshet
```

There should be no output if toshet is not installed. If it is listed in the subsequent output of that command, you can uninstall it by typing the following:

```
sudo apt-get purge toshet
```

Comment: I copied and pasted that code. It has been installed. Unfortunately, the keys are not working yet. Note: during the installation I read the following text: _Starting Apple laptops hotkeys events handler: invoke-rc.d: initscript pommed, action "start" failed_

Comment: @chelder I wouldn't worry about the apple stuff if you're not using an apple it doesn't matter anyway. The only reason I included it was because I'm not really sure package I installed to enable the support I have. I do know that my fn keys did not work after the initial 14.04 installation. The confusion is because I actually fixed the issue by **uninstalling** `toshet`. After reviewing the docks I discovered my model was not listed as a supported laptop. I'll try to see if there is maybe something else that I installed to fix the issue.

Comment: Well, I have uninstalled `toshet`. It is not working yet. Thanks for your help!