# Detect Fn-F1 and Fn-F2 keys on MacBook Pro

Tags: keyboard, lubuntu, brightness, macbook, macbook-pro

I want to map <kbd>Fn</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd> to execution of a command on MacBookPro 11,5. The problem is that currently <kbd>Fn</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd> is not detected as any key. I don't know how to bind these to (XF86MonBrightnessDown) and (XF86MonBrightnessUp)

---

I tried [Some keys are not detected in my keyboard (multimedia keys?) by either xev or xbindkeys or keytouch: how to detect them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/468326/some-keys-are-not-detected-in-my-keyboard-multimedia-keys-by-either-xev-or-xb) but after installing that, xev still can't detect <kbd>Fn</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd> and <kbd>Fn</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd>.

I followed https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AppleKeyboard to set <kbd>Fn</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd> key to work as in normal laptop. This step makes <kbd>Fn</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd> instead of <kbd>F1</kbd> undetectable.

```
Add following line to /etc/modeprob.d/hid_apple.conf:
    options hid_apple fnmode=2

Run the following command:
    sudo update-initramfs -u -k all
```

---

I found scan codes for <kbd>Fn</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd> and <kbd>Fn</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd>

1. switch to console with <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd>.
2. showkey -s
3. press and release <kbd>Fn</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd> and <kbd>Fn</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd>. record scancodes

Result:

```
Fn-F1 pressed
    0xe0 0x4c
Fn-F1 released
    0xe0 0xcc
Fn-F2 pressed
    0xe0 0x54
Fn-F2 released
    0xe0 0xd4
```

---

setkeycodes can't bind any scancode to key code

```
Cannot bind numlock to key_A:
$ setkeycodes 45 30
setkeycodes: failed to set scancode 45 to keycode 30: ioctl KDSETKEYCODE: Invalid argument
```

---

Output of `xmodmap -pk`

```
232     0x1008ff03 (XF86MonBrightnessDown)  0x0000 (NoSymbol)   0x1008ff03 (XF86MonBrightnessDown)  
233     0x1008ff02 (XF86MonBrightnessUp)    0x0000 (NoSymbol)   0x1008ff02 (XF86MonBrightnessUp)
```

---

xev can't distinguish <kbd>Fn</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd> and <kbd>Fn</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd>

```
[Fn-F2 pressed with mouse out of window]
FocusIn event, serial 48, synthetic NO, window 0x2800001,
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyAncestor

KeymapNotify event, serial 48, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  4294967206 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 

[Fn-F2 pressed with mouse in window]
FocusIn event, serial 48, synthetic NO, window 0x2800001,
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyAncestor

KeymapNotify event, serial 48, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 



[Fn-F1 pressed with mouse in window]
FocusIn event, serial 48, synthetic NO, window 0x2800001,
    mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyPointer
KeymapNotify event, serial 48, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  4294967206 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0 

[Fn-F1 pressed with mouse out of window]
FocusIn event, serial 48, synthetic NO, window 0x2800001,
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyAncestor
KeymapNotify event, serial 48, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  

[Fn-F1 released]
FocusOut event, serial 48, synthetic NO, window 0x2800001,
mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyPointer

[F1 key pressed and release]
KeyPress event, serial 48, synthetic NO, window 0x2800001,
    root 0x4a6, subw 0x0, time 2628754, (87,17), root:(88,43),
    state 0x0, keycode 67 (keysym 0xffbe, F1), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 48, synthetic NO, window 0x2800001,
    root 0x4a6, subw 0x0, time 2628906, (87,17), root:(88,43),
    state 0x0, keycode 67 (keysym 0xffbe, F1), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```